# FPDF HTML URI image scheme

Tags: php, fpdf, html2pdf

I have a string for a signature and I want to use FPDF to display the image. Here is my code.

```
<?php
require('c:/xampp/htdocs/html2pdf.php');
$pdf=new PDF_HTML();
$pdf->AddPage();
$text = '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" alt="Signature"/>';
$pdf->WriteHTML($text);
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

I am trying to use [html2pdf.php](http://fpdf.org/en/script/script42.php) and [fpdf version 1.8](http://www.fpdf.org/) to display the image in pdf format. Both html2pdf.php and fpdf.php are in the same directory as my code. but I keep getting this error.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDF_HTML::FPDF() in C:\xampp\htdocs\html2pdf.php on line 52
```

Comment: same here... but still no answer for this problem. have you solve this problem, bro?

Comment: I found the solution here 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18484632/print-base64-coded-image-into-a-fpdf-document

Answer (score 0):

try to change

```
require('c:/xampp/htdocs/html2pdf.php');
```

to

```
require('html2pdf.php');
```