# How to insert base64 image into fpdf?

Tags: php, fpdf

I've seen various answer to this, but for whatever reason I cannot seem to get them to work.

First, I'm pulling the file from my database:

```
try {
    $getQuery = "SELECT * FROM firstForm WHERE id =:id";
    $statement = $db->prepare($getQuery);
    $statement->execute(array(':id' => 2));

    if($row = $statement->fetch()) {
        $fileName = $row['pic'];
    }
}
```

When I echo $fileName it produces "data:image/png;base64..."

How do I convert $fileName so I can use it in fpdf, like so:

```
$pdf = new FPDF('P','in','A4'); // orientation (portrait), inches, ??
$pdf->SetMargins(0.5,0.5,0.5);  // l, t, rs

$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Cell(4,3,'', 1, 2, 'C'); // w, h, text, border width, ???, align
$pdf->Image($fileName);
$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [print BASE64 coded image into a FPDF document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18484632/print-base64-coded-image-into-a-fpdf-document)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although, as suggested by James, the answer [print BASE64 coded image into a FPDF document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18484632/print-base64-coded-image-into-a-fpdf-document) provides a pretty good solution. In your case you could save the following code as `image.php` and then add that image (with `$_GET['id']` set) into the pdf: `$pdf->Image('/image.php?id=2');`. Make sure to check whether the image exists in the database before calling `image.php`.

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] != $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) { // Only allow requests from server.
    header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . "  791 The Internet shut down due to copyright restrictions", true, 791);
    die();
}

if (empty($_GET['id'])) {
    die('Handle this.');
}

// get your $db object in here.
$getQuery = "SELECT * FROM firstForm WHERE id =:id";
$statement = $db->prepare($getQuery);
$statement->execute(array(':id' => 2));

if ($row = $statement->fetch()) {
    $data = $row['pic'];
} else {
    // This shouldn't happening, you should be checking whether firstForm with the id you're calling the image for exists.
}

$exploded = explode(';', $data);
$mimetype = substr($exploded[0], 5);
$data = explode(',', $exploded[1])[1];

header('Content-type: ' . $mimetype);
echo base64_decode($data);
```

You pdf creation would look something like this:

```
$pdf = new FPDF('P','in','A4'); // orientation (portrait), inches, ??
$pdf->SetMargins(0.5,0.5,0.5);  // l, t, rs

$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Cell(4,3,'', 1, 2, 'C'); // w, h, text, border width, ???, align
$pdf->Image('/image.php?id=2');
$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: I'm using cropit to save the image and I don't know how to get cropit to add an id.  Nor do I see how having an id would matter.  I know how to get the data.  I don't know how to use the data in fpdf.  I tried to use the answers from the solution you mentioned and was unable to get any of them to work.

Comment: @Colin Does the edit of my answer help? If not, I'd be happy to explain further.

Comment: @Colin Added example of how pdf creation would look

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured this out. The answer was here in this SO answer [print BASE64 coded image into a FPDF document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18484632/print-base64-coded-image-into-a-fpdf-document) and it works.

The problem was how the image was stored in the database. I had it stored as BLOB when for whatever reason it needs to be stored as LONGBLOG.

Thanks for trying @Nielles.